# Can't access local json file using axios

Tags: ajax, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm having an issue with loading json data locally. My code worked fine when I loaded data from https://randomuser.me/api, but when I specify location of my json file locally it just returns plain HTML. Definitely doing something wrong, but can't figure it out. I use axios for ajax calls. How do I make the request correctly? My code:

```
export function fetchUsers () {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_USER',
        payload: axios.get('./users.json').then( (response) => 
        console.log(response.data) )
    };
}
```

Comment: You are sure you pass the right path, try with absolute path

Comment: Tried the absolute path, got the same result. The path I specified is correct, I even put that file in the same folder with my action creators so that I don't make a mistake.

Comment: tried using fetch, it said that it makes a request to http://localhost:7770/users.json, which is not quite what I want.

Comment: For me you do not need axios for that, you can do a simple
import users from './users.json';
And you make a 
export default const users = () => new Promise (resolve, reject) {resolve (users); }

Comment: If it's not clear I can put an answer on your question

Comment: A good idea came to my mind while thinking about how to get around this issue, so I decided to rebuild my app a little bit, using another external api that, hopefully, won't cause any problems. Thanks for trying to help anyway!

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path starting with file:/// ?

Comment: I don't remember,bro, It was 3 months ago. I didn't find a way a to fix this issue and rewrote half of the pet-project in which this problem appeared, lol.

Comment: @Umbrella would like to share which solution you have implemented?

Comment: @KiranJasvanee The right way to do this is to import a json file like this, if the file is on your machine: "import users from './users.json", you might need to set up a json-loader in webpack for that to work. If it's on the server you should be able to access it with axios by url. You shouldn't try to access local files with axios as I was trying to do, use import statement instead,.